# Repeat a task- array job N times

Tags: bash, sungridengine

I have 17 files and I'm running a task - array job on these 17 files. But now I need to run my command 10 times on each of these 17 input files. The input file will be the same in all cases

```
input${SGE_TASK_ID}
```

But I want the output file to look a bit like this

```
output${SGE_TASK_ID}_order${1/2/3/5../10}
```

So basically, I want to run a task array N times. Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Just use a nested for-loop inside your primary for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have the hard stuff, it's a basic nested loop.  Here's an example.

```
for file in *.txt; do
    for i in {1..10}; do
        command < input$SGE_TASK_ID >output${SGE_TASK_ID}_order$i
    done
done
```

edit: I hope you've learn how to accept answers since your last post.

Comment: Thanks for the response!